# Google Custom Search - Results in IE shifting page left

Tags: google-custom-search

I am having some issues with a google custom search implementation. I have it working perfectly in FF, Chrome, Safari in the development environment. However in IE when clicking a next page (number at the bottom) the page alignment is skewed.

I have uploaded the code into production environment on a text page so that you can see this first hand: http://www.brookson.co.uk/test99/tests/?q=tax (I have included the search param, as the search box is not currently linked to the google custom search.

Any help would be appreciated.